# Change color of link on hover within Google Sites

Tags: google-sites

How can you change the color of a link within Google Sites when the mouse hovers over the link?

Answer (score 2):

Although I have not used Google Sites, I believe the problem you are having is that it does not let you add custom CSS?

Having checked Google and finding a "[CSS Workaround](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/sites/thread?tid=6f5423cf1633135d&hl=en)" I see that while you cannot add custom CSS, you can add custom HTML. Although most people prefer using CSS for styling, you can still add CSS to the attributes in HTML.

For example:

```
<a href="#"onmouseover="this.style.color='#ffffff';"    onmouseout="this.style.color='#000000';" style="color:#000000;">Link</a>
```

While I have not tested this in Google Sites, I am 90% sure it will work. Unless they do not allow inline Javascript either, in which case I am sorry and there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Google site clearing inline javascript.

You should use HTML Box (https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en) for features as hover. Allows you to use custom css and javascript.

Unfortunately, HTML Box content is displayed on page with delay